# AFNetworking - How to get data from cache when no internet connection? iOS

Tags: afnetworking

Is it really? Or I should check internet connection and get from custom cache data?
For example:
I load via AFNetworking JSON by URL_JSON when good connection. Then connection falls. Then I request URL_JSON and I should get the same JSON as when was good connection.

How it make better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in the failure block for a request that you want to use the cached response (if available)

```
 NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]     cachedResponseForRequest:request];
if (cachedResponse != nil &&
    [[cachedResponse data] length] > 0)
{
    // Get cached data
    ....
}
```

as mentioned in this link 
  https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/566